# Not receiving POST Data on other end of cURL Request

Tags: php, rest, post, curl, put

I have a curl request as below, which should send a PUT request to a PHP file on my webserver. When I receive this request, I want to list all of the POST data received with this PUT request, but no POST data is received. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fields = array(
        'username' => 'username'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/linetime/user/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data sent with `PUT` requests is not available through `$_POST`.

Take a look at what `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` tells you. It's `multipart/form-data` usually with a boundary like in MIME mails. You can read the `PUT` data using the input stream:

```
$putData = '';
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $s = fread($fp, 64);
    $putData .= $s;
}
fclose($fp);
```

In your case, `$putData` should now contain something like:

```
------------------------------e85bfe7e43b5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

username
------------------------------e85bfe7e43b5--
```

Now, all you'll need is to parse this data using one of the many freely available PEAR packages for MIME handling.

Comment: And for easy access to the inputstream, `$input = file_get_contents("php://input");` is also available.